# Possibly similar question (or even accounts)?

Tags: support, duplicates

Either it's a coincidence or intentional, I saw two similar questions of LibreOffice right now:

[Convert .ods document to .docx document](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039715/conver-ods-document-to-docx-document)

[Converting .ods to .docx file](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1039699/converting-ods-to-docx-file)

Apparently, both OPs have also the similar amount and topic of questions (with only one user have *one more* question, which is tagged as duplicate). I don't think they belong to one person, but their typing style somehow increases my suspicion between them.

Can anyone take a look and investigate this? They even have almost *similar* typos, incorrectly typing `.odt` as `.ods`.

Comment: Flagging the question would be enough to alert a mod ;-)

Comment: Flagged both questions.